# Increasing the quality of EMF outputs in R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, .emf

I am generating and saving an EMF file with ggplot2 and with the win.graph command. the output graph is low quality and lines looked jagged. I really need to have it in EMF format (exporting to pdf solves the problem but I need the EMF file). How can I make it high quality? (the emf output is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10279222/ggplot2emf-stack.emf) in case you like to see it)

```
require(ggplot2)
my.dates = as.Date(c("2011-07-22","2011-07-23",
                     "2011-07-24","2011-07-28","2011-07-29"))
my.vals  = c(5,6,8,7,3)
my.data <- data.frame(date =my.dates, vals = my.vals)
plot(my.dates, my.vals)
p <- ggplot(data = my.data, aes(date,vals))+ geom_line(size = 1.5)
p <- p + scale_x_date(format="%m/%d", ' ')
win.graph(width=860/72, height=450/72,pointsize = 12)

print(p)
savePlot("c:/test.emf",type="emf")
dev.off()
```

Comment: You can use `ggsave` to eliminate a few lines of code: `ggsave("c:/test.emf", p)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EMF is vector based. I was pasting the EMF files into powerpoint slides and I noticed that they are rendered as low res. If you right click on the EMF file and select edit photo it will render it properly. That solved my problem.

**Update:**
I went ahead and wrote a little VBA script that ungroups the EMF file. It breaks it into a graph object that can be easily scaled. It looks very nice now.

Comment: Did you have similar problems in MS Word? The right click + `edit picture` trick does not function in my case. Resolution seems ok, but graphical elements (e.g. point symbols) are slightly distorted.

Answer (score -1):

You can save your ggplot as SVG and then post-process it with Inkscape. 
It's easy to use, free and gives great results.